# INNER LOOP JOIN Failing

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, join-hints

I need to update a field called `FamName` in a table called `Episode` with randomly generated Germanic names from a different table called `Surnames` which has a single column called `Surname`.

To do this I have first added an `ID` field and `NONCLUSTERED INDEX` to my `Surnames` table

```
ALTER TABLE Surnames 
ADD ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1);
GO
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx ON Surnames(ID);
GO
```

I then attempt to update my `Episode` table via

```
UPDATE E  
SET E.FamName = S.Surnames 
FROM Episode AS E 
INNER LOOP JOIN Surnames AS S 
    ON S.ID = (1 + ABS(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(8) % (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Surnames)));
GO
```

where I am attempting to force the query to 'loop' using the `LOOP` join hint. Of course if I don't force the optimizer to loop (using `LOOP`) I will get the same German name for all rows. However, this query is strangely returning zero rows affected.

**Why is this returning zero affected rows and how can this be amended to work?**

---

*Note, I could use a `WHILE` loop to perform this update, but I want a succinct way of doing this and to find out what I am doing wrong in this particular case.*

Comment: Why are you using `LOOP` join,let the query optimizer decided whether it wants to do a LOOP , MERGE or HASH join

Comment: When you run this query: `SELECT * FROM Episode AS E 
INNER LOOP JOIN Surnames AS S 
    ON S.ID = (1 + ABS(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(8) % (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Surnames)));` how many rows returned? My guess is 0. that means you probably have something wrong with your `JOIN` criteria (i.e the `ON` part)

Comment: @Yosi I explained _why_ in the question. Without the loop all rows get returned, _again_ this was stated in the question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot (reliably) affect query results with join hints. They are performance hints, not semantic hints. You try to rely on undefined behavior.

Moving the random number computation out of the join condition into one of the join sources prevents the expression to be treated as a constant:

```
UPDATE E  
SET E.FamName = S.Surnames 
FROM (
 SELECT *, (1 + ABS(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(8) % (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Surnames))) AS SurnameID
 FROM Episode AS E 
) E
INNER LOOP JOIN Surnames AS S ON S.ID = E.SurnameID
```

The derived table `E` adds the computed `SurnameID` as a new column.

You don't need join hints any longer. I just tested that this works in my specific test case although I'm not whether this is guaranteed to work.

Comment: I added it. Almost nothing else changed. My answers are sometimes a little short...

Comment: I released after I asked. Sorry to waste your time... Thanks very much, nice simple approach. I also learned something about join hints so thanks.